# Using R Shiny to save a user's input from a textbox field to an XML file

Tags: javascript, r, xml, shiny

I have an R Shiny application where it has two panels. The first panel has a dropdown menu with multiple options. For each option in the dropdown menu, the appropriate variable name and its value appears in a textbox format. For the second panel, it has several textboxes with its variable names and values.

All the information is extracted from an XML file.

There's an update button in the first button, which updates the XML file based on the user's changes to the textboxes. The issue I'm having is that the XML does update for the changes that occurred in the second panel only, and not the first panel.

When the user clicks the **Update** button, I'd like the XML file to update the changes that occurred in the first and second panel.

Below is my code and the XML file.

```
library(shiny)
library(xml2)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyBS)
library(XML)

xml_file <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/leaf_default.xml"
xml_data <- read_xml(xml_file)

leaf_static <- read_xml("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/init_files/leaf_user_static.xml")

leaf_pars <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//pars/leaf")
leaf_pars_name <- xml_children(leaf_pars) %>% xml_name()
leaf_pars_value <- xml_children(leaf_pars) %>% xml_text()

leaf_pars_ggc <- xml_find_all(leaf_pars, ".//*[count(*) > 1]") %>% xml_name()

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
           wellPanel(
             prettyRadioButtons(
               "parts",
               "Please Select",
               choices = "pars",
               status = "danger",
               fill = TRUE
             )
           )
    ), 
    column(10, 
           bsCollapse(id = "collapse_ex", open = "Parameters", multiple = TRUE,
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters w/Sub-Script", 
                                      selectInput("gc_pars", "Select Parameter", choices = leaf_pars_ggc),
                                      uiOutput("grandchild_textboxes"),
                                      style = "success", 
                                      fluidRow(
                                        column(12, align = "right",
                                               actionButton("update_button", "Update")
                                        )
                                      )
                      ),
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters", 
                                      uiOutput("ui"), 
                                      style = "info"
                      )
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  pars_gc_names <- reactiveValues(names = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$parts, {
    leaf_pars <- leaf_pars_name
    
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(
        lapply(leaf_pars, function(node_name) {
          if (node_name %in% leaf_pars_ggc) {
            return(NULL)
          }
          if (node_name %in% leaf_pars_name) {
            node_index <- match(node_name, leaf_pars_name)
            default_value <- leaf_pars_value[node_index]
            
            column(6, textInput(node_name, label = node_name, value = default_value))
          } 
        }) 
      )
    })
    
    output$grandchild_textboxes <- renderUI({
      pars_gc_options <- input$gc_pars # grandchild_options gets the selected parameter from the dropdown menu
      
      pars_grandchilds <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(paste0(".//pars/leaf/", pars_gc_options))
      pars_gc_names$names <- xml_children(pars_grandchilds) %>% xml_name() # Update the reactive value
      pars_gc_values <- xml_children(pars_grandchilds) %>% xml_text()
      
      lapply(pars_gc_names$names, function(pars_gc_nodes) {
        pars_node_index <- match(pars_gc_nodes, pars_gc_names$names)
        pars_def_value <- pars_gc_values[pars_node_index]
        
        column(6, textInput(pars_gc_nodes, label = pars_gc_nodes, value = pars_def_value))
      })
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update_button, {
    # Retrieve the input data from the "Parameters w/Sub-Script" panel
    input_data <- lapply(pars_gc_names$names, function(pars_gc_nodes) {
      if (pars_gc_nodes %in% pars_gc_names$names) {
        input_value <- input[[pars_gc_nodes]]
        return(list(node_name = pars_gc_nodes, value = input_value))
      }
    })
    # print(input_data)
    
    for (input_item in input_data) {
      if (!is.null(input_item)) {
        # print("Input:", input_item$node_name, "Value:", input_item$value, "\n")
        print(input_item$value)
      }
    }
  })

  
  observeEvent(input$update_button, {
    # Create a copy of the XML data
    updated_xml_data <- xml_data

    # Update the values in the XML data based on the user input
    for (node_name in leaf_pars_name) {
      if (node_name %in% leaf_pars_ggc) {
        next
      }

      new_value <- input[[node_name]]

      # Find the corresponding XML node and update its text
      node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//pars/leaf/", node_name))
      if (!is.null(node)) {
        xml_text(node) <- new_value
      }
    }

    # Save the updated XML data to a new file
    new_xml_file <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/test/updated_leaf.xml"
    write_xml(updated_xml_data, new_xml_file)

    # Show a success message or perform any additional actions
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Update Successful",
      "The XML file has been updated.",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
<dynamic>
  <pars>
    <leaf>
      <d13c>NA</d13c>
      <deltaA_prop>NA</deltaA_prop>
      <solver_min>NA</solver_min>
      <solver_max>NA</solver_max>
      <a>NA</a>
      <f>NA</f>
      <quantum_yield_to_eff>NA</quantum_yield_to_eff>
      <ko_kc_ratio>NA</ko_kc_ratio>
      <theta_j>NA</theta_j>
      <theta_col_cj>NA</theta_col_cj>
      <theta_col_cjp>NA</theta_col_cjp>
      <avn_25>NA</avn_25>
      <bvn_25>NA</bvn_25>
      <ajv_25>NA</ajv_25>
      <bjv_25>NA</bjv_25>
      <a_jvt_25>NA</a_jvt_25>
      <b_jvt_25>NA</b_jvt_25>
      <c_jvt_25>NA</c_jvt_25>
      <e_ajv_25>NA</e_ajv_25>
      <e_bjv_25>NA</e_bjv_25>
      <atv_25>NA</atv_25>
      <btv_25>NA</btv_25>
      <akv_25>NA</akv_25>
      <bkv_25>NA</bkv_25>
      <flnr>NA</flnr>
      <fnr>NA</fnr>
      <Rsa>NA</Rsa>
      <Apg_alpha>NA</Apg_alpha>
      <g0>NA</g0>
      <g1_medlyn>NA</g1_medlyn>
      <g1_leuning>NA</g1_leuning>
      <d0>NA</d0>
      <g1_ball>NA</g1_ball>
      <g_a1_yin>NA</g_a1_yin>
      <g_b1_yin>NA</g_b1_yin>
      <rs>NA</rs>
      <cica_chi>NA</cica_chi>
      <rb>NA</rb>
      <can_ttc>NA</can_ttc>
      <leaf_width>NA</leaf_width>
      <ri>NA</ri>
      <co2_diff>NA</co2_diff>
      <hco_co2_ratio>NA</hco_co2_ratio>
      <hco_co2_diff_ratio>NA</hco_co2_diff_ratio>
      <d13c_a>NA</d13c_a>
      <d13c_b>NA</d13c_b>
      <d13c_b_prime>NA</d13c_b_prime>
      <d13c_am>NA</d13c_am>
      <d13c_f>NA</d13c_f>
      <a_rdv_25>NA</a_rdv_25>
      <b_rdv_25>NA</b_rdv_25>
      <a_rdn_25>NA</a_rdn_25>
      <b_rdn_25>NA</b_rdn_25>
      <rl_rd_ratio>NA</rl_rd_ratio>
      <rl_rd_lloyd_a>NA</rl_rd_lloyd_a>
      <rl_rd_lloyd_b>NA</rl_rd_lloyd_b>
      <a_rdv_25_t>NA</a_rdv_25_t>
      <b_rdv_25_t>NA</b_rdv_25_t>
      <home_temp>NA</home_temp>
      <reftemp>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
        <Kc>NA</Kc>
        <Ko>NA</Ko>
        <gstar>NA</gstar>
        <tau>NA</tau>
      </reftemp>
      <atref>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
        <Kc>NA</Kc>
        <Ko>NA</Ko>
        <gstar>NA</gstar>
        <tau>NA</tau>
        <vomax>NA</vomax>
      </atref>
      <Ha>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
        <Kc>NA</Kc>
        <Ko>NA</Ko>
        <gstar>NA</gstar>
        <tau>NA</tau>
        <vomax>NA</vomax>
      </Ha>
      <Hd>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
      </Hd>
      <Topt>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
      </Topt>
      <deltaS>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
      </deltaS>
      <a_deltaS_t>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
      </a_deltaS_t>
      <b_deltaS_t>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
      </b_deltaS_t>
      <c_deltaS_t>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
      </c_deltaS_t>
      <q10>
        <rd>NA</rd>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <jmax>NA</jmax>
        <tpu>NA</tpu>
        <k_pepc>NA</k_pepc>
        <Kc>NA</Kc>
        <Ko>NA</Ko>
        <tau>NA</tau>
      </q10>
      <a_q10_t>
        <rd>NA</rd>
      </a_q10_t>
      <b_q10_t>
        <rd>NA</rd>
      </b_q10_t>
      <tupp_cox>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <rd>NA</rd>
      </tupp_cox>
      <tlow_cox>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <rd>NA</rd>
      </tlow_cox>
      <exp_cox>
        <vcmax>NA</vcmax>
        <rd>NA</rd>
      </exp_cox>
      <gstar_bf_a>NA</gstar_bf_a>
      <gstar_bf_b>NA</gstar_bf_b>
      <gstar_bf_c>NA</gstar_bf_c>
      <R>NA</R>
    </leaf>
  </pars>
</dynamic>
```